# how to remove shadow on hover in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

could you please tell me how to remove shadow on hover in highchart ? When I hover the any slice it give shadow .
here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/oupmgvjy/11/

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        credits: {
         enabled: false
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            layout: 'vertical',
            x: 0,
            y: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Election'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
               series: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
            },
                allowPointSelect: false,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<b>{point.y}</b>',

                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                },

                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 270,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
            shadow: false
        },
        series: [{
          showInLegend: false,
            name: 'election result',
            enabled: true,
               dataLabels: {
                   enabled: false
                },
            data: [
                ['A', 55],
                ['B', 65],

            ],
            size: '30%',
            innerSize: '70%',
        }, {
            name: 'Versions',
            data: [
                ['a', 55],
                ['b', 65],
                ['c', 65],
                ['d', 132],

            ],
            size: '70%',
            innerSize: '80%',

        }]
    });
});
```

in other words I need to remove shadow on hover .I already use `shadow: false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is achieved throug plotOptions -> series -> states -> hover. You just have to add the next option inside plotOption:

```
series: {states: {hover: {enabled: false}}},
```

Here you have the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.states.hover).

Please, if this answer your question, mark it as solved :)

Comment: I've modified your code and it works fine for me. Be sure to have plotOptions like this:

plotOptions: {
          series: {
              states: {
                hover: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              }
            },
            pie: {...}...
        }

Comment: I want to show `A/B` in center ..In other words can I show `55/65`  which is A/Bin middle of both donut chart